# SQL Date Modification

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

This may seem like a trivial question but I have been working on this for two hours. Basically I need to get the start of the year, i.e. 01/01/2013 from 09/25/2013 by manipulation of the current date.

I have been able to get the beginning of the month but I can't figure out how to get the beginning of the year.

My Code:

```
SET :testDate = curdate() - DAYOFMONTH(curDAate()) + 1
```

This got me the first day of the month but I do not know how to do the same thing but allow it so subtract months instead of days.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server?

Comment: It is Pervasive Control Center version 11.20.015.000 sorry for the confusion

Comment: What kind of SQL is this?  I don't recognize that format nor the DAYOFMONTH function.

Comment: If you are looking for beginning of year, wouldn't knowing the current date help you form date as `01/01/2012` from say `12/10/2012`?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do however I do not know how to manipulate the month.

Comment: http://help.pervasive.com/display/DI1025/DatePart+Function Check out the datepart function.

Comment: @Telexx - Funniest thing I've seen in a long time on that page. `Caution
This function returns a value that must be used or stored to prevent stack overflow. See Stack Overflow.`

Comment: Is there a way that I could simply create a new date and set testDate to that new date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these will do:

```
    = CURDATE() - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) + 1
```

or:

```
    = CONVERT( CONCAT( YEAR(CURDATE(), '-01-01' ), SQL_DATE )
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
set :test = DATEADD(month, -month(curdate())+1, curdate()) - DAYOFMONTH(curDate()) +1
```

Thanks for the help!